# VBA - Paste Event and undo last action of Paste

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make my excel to Paste Values instead of PasteAll by using VBA. But I'm not able to achieve it due to failure of the line :

```
lastAction = Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo").List(1)
```

I'm using code as below. Could anyone kindly help me to solve this? please correct my code as well if I'm wrong.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim lastAction As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

lastAction = Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo").List(1)


If Left(lastAction, 5) = "Paste" Then

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

Application.Undo


Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: see here for more complete version: http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/09/17/vba-excelallow-paste-special-only/

Comment: Many Thanks Scott for this one. This really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

After including above code, I understood that this doesn't helps if the content copied was not from Excel. Below code helps to handle the data from both Office Clipboard and Windows Clipboard.

Office Clipboard - Paste as Values
Windows Clipboard - Paste as text

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim UndoList As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    '~~> Get the undo List to capture the last action performed by user
    UndoList = Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo").List(1)

    '~~> Check if the last action was not a paste nor an autofill
    If Left(UndoList, 5) = "Paste" Or UndoList = "Paste special" Then
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    
    On Error GoTo 0

    '~~> Undo the paste that the user did but we are not clearing the
    '~~> clipboard so the copied data is still in memory
    Application.Undo

    
    '~~> Do a pastespecial to preserve formats
    
    '~~> Handle text data copied from a website
     
    'Target.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
     
    'Target.PasteSpecial Paste:="Text", Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False
    
     Call Paste_Event
   
    
    On Error GoTo 0

    '~~> Retain selection of the pasted data
    Union(Target, Selection).Select
    
    End If

Application.EnableEvents = True

LetsContinue:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
    
End Sub


Private Sub Paste_Event()

On Error GoTo Paste
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Exit Sub
On Error GoTo 0
Paste:
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:="Text", Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False
Exit Sub

End Sub
```

---

Answer (score -1):

Here is the perfect solution which i found

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim UndoList As String
 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
 
    On Error GoTo Whoa
 
    '~~> Get the undo List to capture the last action performed by user
    UndoList = Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo").List(1)
 
    '~~> Check if the last action was not a paste nor an autofill
    If Left(UndoList, 5) = "Paste" Or UndoList = "Paste special" Then
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    
    On Error GoTo 0
 
    '~~> Undo the paste that the user did but we are not clearing the
    '~~> clipboard so the copied data is still in memory
    Application.Undo
 
    
    '~~> Do a pastespecial to preserve formats
    
    '~~> Handle text data copied from a website
     
    Target.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    On Error GoTo 0
 
    '~~> Retain selection of the pasted data
    Union(Target, Selection).Select
    
    End If
 
 Application.EnableEvents = True
 
LetsContinue:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

Comment: If you  "found" this code, you must include proper attribution,  otherwise it's plagiarism.   Assuming,  of course,  that the source licensing allows you to repost it

Comment: Hi @chrisneilsen, I mean I worked on it and got it worked based on my requirement and possible issues I found during the usage of original code. Not taken from anywhere else.